# Append ORDER BY syntax to php MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a ORDER BY syntax to a MySQL join query I am performing in PHP.  I am using an already defined session variable to dynamically select criteria.

Works fine:

```
$query_icons = sprintf("SELECT i.id, i.name, e.EmpNo FROM gbl_icons i LEFT JOIN gbl_empicons e ON e.IconId = i.id AND e.EmpNo = %s", GetSQLValueString($ParamEmpNo_WADAgbl_qemplisting, "text"));
```

When I try to append ORDER BY it throws a 500 Internal Server Error:

```
$query_icons = sprintf("SELECT i.id, i.name, e.EmpNo FROM gbl_icons i LEFT JOIN gbl_empicons e ON e.IconId = i.id AND e.EmpNo = %s", GetSQLValueString($ParamEmpNo_WADAgbl_qemplisting, "text")ORDER BY i.id ASC);
```

How do I properly escape the dynamic session value properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this:

```
$query_icons = sprintf("SELECT i.id, i.name, e.EmpNo FROM gbl_icons i LEFT JOIN gbl_empicons e ON e.IconId = i.id AND e.EmpNo = %s", GetSQLValueString($ParamEmpNo_WADAgbl_qemplisting, "text")."ORDER BY i.id ASC");
```

you forgot to enclode the ORDER BY i.id ASC in " so that you got a serious syntax error

as mentiond in the comment this would work too:

```
$query_icons = sprintf("SELECT i.id, i.name, e.EmpNo FROM gbl_icons i LEFT JOIN gbl_empicons e ON e.IconId = i.id AND e.EmpNo = %s ORDER BY i.id ASC", GetSQLValueString($ParamEmpNo_WADAgbl_qemplisting, "text"));
```

Comment: Why not just put it in the primary string?

Comment: Are you sure that first part [will work with `sprintf()`](http://codepad.org/8PCas5t8)?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes since "%s" means string

Comment: Right. So the first part in all likelihood doesn't resolve the problem past the parse error.

Comment: @JaredFarrish what problem didn't it resolve? he said that the server gave a 500 error which was caused by the parse error. Any logical or other Error is not part of the question..

Comment: It produces a SQL string that's obviously tending to broken. I guess that makes perfect sense.

Comment: @JaredFarrish it depends on how his `GetSQLValueString` function works. if it wraps something like this: `'something'` without any space then it might end up wrong yes. but if there is a space then it will work fine. although it is nonsense..

Answer (score 2):

put the ORDER BY inside the string , after the "%s".

as an addition, it's very unsafe to forge SQL queries into a string directly,  try using PDO or other data access layer to create safe parameterized requests.

```
$query_icons = sprintf("SELECT i.id, i.name, e.EmpNo FROM gbl_icons i LEFT JOIN gbl_empicons e ON e.IconId = i.id AND e.EmpNo = %s ORDER BY i.id ASC", GetSQLValueString($ParamEmpNo_WADAgbl_qemplisting, "text"));
```